-undefined dynamic_lookup is deprecated on iOS
Since an unknown time I'm getting the warning: -undefined dynamic_lookup is deprecated on iOS  in Xcode.
As a backend I have Firebase, anyone have any idea how to resolve or investigate this?
This post is an duplicate of this item, but in 8 years there haven't been any responses.
